# Rails 4 scope not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 4 app, the scope isn't working for me.

Model:

```
class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  scope :completed, -> { where(completed: true) }
  scope :notcompleted, -> { where(completed: false) }
end
```

Routes:

```
  get 'todos/completed'
```

Controller:

```
class TodosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_todo, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def completed
  @todos = current_user.todos.completed
end
...
def set_todo
  @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])
end
```

View:

```
...
<% @todos.each do |todo| %>
...
```

I'm getting:

```
Couldn't find Todo with 'id'=completed
in the set_todo logic
```

I don't understand why it is hitting the `set_todo` logic. It runs `set_todo` even if I use something like `before_action :set_todo, except: [:index, :create, :completed]`

Somehow, the code `set_todo` needs to not get executed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :todos do
   get :completed, on: :collection #-> url.com/todos/completed
end
```

---

**Explained**

Your old routes probably looked like this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :todos
get "todos/complete"
```

When you send a request to Rails, it looks through the routes and matches the one which you're requesting.

With `resources :todos`, you get the route `/todos/:id`.

This means that any time you request the url `url.com/todos/x`, Rails will invoke the `todos#show` action, which is populated by `set_todo`.

This is why you receive the `Couldn't find Todo with 'id'=completed` error -- Rails is sending your request to the *show* action.

What you need is *either* to define `get 'todos/complete'` *above* `resources :todos`:

```
#config/routes.rb
get "todos/complete"
resources :todos
```

... OR (recommended), [create an extra route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-collection-routes):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :todos do
  get :completed, on: :collection
end
```

---

As an aside, your *scopes* could be cleaned up a little:

```
#app/models/todo.rb
class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
   scope :completed, ->(trigger = true) { where completed: trigger }
end
```

This will allow you to use the single `completed` scope with a passed argument:

```
@todos.completed
@todos.completed(false)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure scopes work on the collection generated by `current_user.todos`. As seen in [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html), scoping is a class method that acts on the model.

if you reverse the query, it should be fine.

`Todo.completed.where(user_id: current_user.id)`

Comment: While this is definitely true, that would be really dirty and misleading as a part of a controller action.

Comment: do you have a one-to-many association set up between the users and the todo models? also, if you comment out the code in `set_todo` does this issue go away (i.e. youre sure its being caused here)
@ABMagil why is that?

Comment: I take it back- I thought we were working in `UsersController`, not `TodosController`. I retract my comment!

Answer (score 0):

use class method

```
 def self.completed 
   where(completed: true) 
 end
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html

Comment: From the link you posted: "...this is simply 'syntactic sugar' for defining an actual class method:"

Answer (score 0):

Try this scope:

```
scope :completed, proc{ |todo| where('completed = ?', true) }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting isn't in the scope, but in your `.find` logic. Your `set_todo` runs `Todo.find(params[:id])`. <strike>There's no reason to do this for the `completed` controller action, since it has all the information it needs without using the params hash (there is no user input required to find out which records are completed).</strike>

The other issue is that your `params[:id]` probably shouldn't be getting populated in this case at all, since it appears `/todos/completed` looks like a collection route.

Instead of putting `get todos/complete`, I would nest it under your `todo` resource:

```
resources :todos do
  collection do
    get 'completed'
  end
end
```

Or explicitly dictate the route mapping

```
get '/todos/completed', to: 'todos#completed'
```

As it is, it looks like `get todos/completed` is hitting the wrong part of the routing table.

Finally, you might want to just create a "completed_todos" association on `User`, which will move the logic into the model (where I would argue it belongs)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :todos
  has_many :completed_todos, -> { where(completed: true) }
end
```

Comment: `has_many :completed_todos, -> { completed: true }` didn't work. Don't I need some reference to todos - like self.todo.completed?

Comment: Updated to change.  Was missing a where.  The issue about hitting `set_todo` is the `routes.rb` thing in my second paragraph.

Comment: `get 'todos/controller', to: 'todos/completed'` gives me `Missing :action key on routes definition, please check your routes.`

Comment: What about when you use the nested collection route (the first suggestion)? All this syntax is from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: undefined local variable or method `todos_completed_path'

Comment: completed_todos_path worked - but, get same error on set_todo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93541/discussion-between-abmagil-and-reddirt).

Comment: The last place you should check is your routing table.  You can access this from the command line with `rake routes`. If the `completed` route doesn't show up before all the others, that's your problem.